# why is the count backwards

Tags: python, list

I have the following code but I can not understand why the result shows a count going backwards if no `-1` is used

```
def strange(n):
    list = []

    for i in range(0, n):
        list.insert(0, i)

    return list


print(strange(15))
```

Comment: Python `insert()` is different from `append()`. It adds the element based on the position you specified in the parameter, while `append()` always adds to the last position. Try `print(list)` inside the loop to see the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears backwards because of this line of code:

```
list.insert(0, i)
```

Every time you insert a value, it is saved to index `0`, so the resulting list goes backward.

If you you use the `append` method instead, it will be in ascending order. You can also replace the `0` in `insert` with some other number, which will put the value at that position, if the index exists.

Answer (score 2):

You fetch each value in the list in order, but when you insert data, it is always inserted to 0 (beginning on the left side of the list)

Answer (score 1):

Because insert inserts before index

```
arr = [1,2,3]
arr.insert(0, 0)
print(arr) # -> [0,1,2,3]
```

Use .append(i) instead, it will add obj at the end of the list

Or you can use _list.insert(i, i) which will append obj to the end too

```
def strange(n): 
    _list = []
    for i in range(0, n):
        _list.append(i)

    return _list

print(strange(15))
```

And also, don't call your variable as a built-in type list, it's bad practice, because you can't access it anymore, it will be rewritten with your new value.